# Trouble with creating permutations of a set in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, vector, stl, set

I have a `set` of 4 rectangles. Each rectangle is a `pair<int, int>` of length & breadth.
I try to produce permutations of this set. However, this code throws a segmentation fault
when I try to run it. I can't figure out the problem.

Here's the code:

```
void permute(set<pair<int, int> >& rectangles, vector<pair<int, int> >& sequence) {
    if(rectangles.empty()) {
        // read this sequence.
        return;
    }
    set<pair<int, int> >::iterator rect;
    for(rect = rectangles.begin(); rect != rectangles.end(); rect++) {
        rectangles.erase(*rect);
        sequence.push_back(*rect);
        permute(rectangles, sequence);
        sequence.pop_back();
        rectangles.insert(*rect);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `rectangles.ersase(*rect);` invalidates all iterator to the element (see [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase)). This means that you can no longer dereference the iterator in the rest of the loop.

You'll need to copy the value before calling erase, and use that copy instead of dereferencing the iterator:

```
pair<int, int> copy = *rect;
rectangles.erase(rect);
sequence.push_back(copy);
permute(rectangles, sequence);
sequence.pop_back();
rectangles.insert(copy);
```

Comment: Hi, in the above code snippet, changing `pair<int, int>` everywhere with `int` leads to a segmentation fault despite your correction. Any idea why?